# How to add a member to a directory role using the msgraph-sdk-java

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to do the following

```
IDirectoryObjectWithReferenceRequest request = graphServiceClient.directoryRoles(roleId).members("$ref").buildRequest();
DirectoryObject o = new DirectoryObject();
o.id = "someid";
request.post(null, o);
```

and get a 400.  What is the second parameter object that needs to be passed to post?  What is the first parameter that needs to be passed to post?  Documentation states to pass as the body:

```
{"@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}" }
```

Also, what is the deal with the first parameter to post?  It gets returned right back if it's a success?  That seems like a very unusual way of reporting success/failure.

Comment: I think I tracked down the right object to use, it should be ReferenceRequestBody instead of DirectoryObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the above is just completely wrong.  Here is how it's supposed to be done:

```
        DirectoryObject o = new DirectoryObject();
        o.id = objectId;
        requireDelegatedPermissions = true;
        IDirectoryObjectCollectionReferenceRequest request = graphServiceClient.directoryRoles(roleId).members().references().buildRequest();
        return request.post(o);
```